# Triple quote escape ambiguity

Tags: python, string

```
>>> sample7 = """including 'quote1' "quote2" and 'quote3" """
>>> sample7
'including \'quote1\' "quote2" and \'quote3" '
>>> print sample7
including 'quote1' "quote2" and 'quote3"
```

Here, the quotes inside the string `sample7` was properly escaped by the triple quotes. But,

```
>>> sample4 = """c:\ntext\text\file.rtf"""
>>> sample4
'c:\ntext\text\x0cile.rtf'
>>> print sample4
c:
text    extile.rtf
```

The backslashes in `sample4` were not properly escaped by the triple quote. Why is that? What should be done to escape that automatically. Something like,

```
String file = @"c:\ntext\text\file.rtf";
```

in C#.

PS. Also, how did I get `\x0cile.rtf` instead of `\file.rtf`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python is evaluating \f Just use raw strings

```
r"c:\ntext\text\file.rtf"
```

Comment: @mirabilos I couldn't find any escape sequences which were not ignored by a raw string. The only exception is that a raw string cannot end with an odd number of slashes. E.g. `print r"test\\\\"` yields test\\\\ but `print r"test\\\"` gives an error.

Comment: @Jim Right, exactly. This is a really problematic thing for automated escapes. Compare shell, where it’s utterly easy: prefix `'`, postfix `'`, replace all `'` inside by `'\''`, done.